# STL list iterator won't update my object

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am using a list iterator to set all the ages of the Pets to 1 but the change won't persist outside the for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Pet{
  public:
  int age;
};

class Person{
  public:
  list<Pet> pets;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Person bob;
  Pet p1;
  p1.age = 0;
  bob.pets.push_back(p1);

  cout << "Start with: "<<p1.age << endl;

  std::list<Pet>::iterator itPet;
  for (itPet = bob.pets.begin(); itPet != bob.pets.end(); ++itPet) {
    Pet p = (*itPet);
    p.age = 1;
    cout << "Right after setting to 1: "<<p.age << endl;
  }

  cout << "After the for loop: "<<p1.age << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Start with: 0
Right after setting to 1: 1
After the for loop: 0
```

Why is p1 not updated? And what has been updated if not p1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just modify a copy: the statement

```
Pet p = (*itPet);
```

copies the value of `*itPet` to `p` which then gets updated. You can verify that the object used by the iterator by using this code:

```
p.age = 1;
cout << "Right after setting to 1: p.age="<<p.age << " itPet->age=" << itPet->age << '\n';
```

You want to us a reference:

```
Pet& p = *itPet;
```

The approach you are using to verify whether the objects in the list are changed doesn't work, either, though: the standard C++ library containers make a copy of the objects inserted and don't keep a reference to the original object. That is, `p1` won't be changed but the element in the list is changed:

```
for (std::list<Pet>::const_iterator it(bob.pets.begin()), end(bob.pets.end());
     it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << "list after change: " << it->age << '\n';
}
```

Comment: If I use Pet& p = *itPet; the change still doesn't persist after the for loop.

Comment: @ben: it does. However, you are looking at a copy you made earlier which is, of course, not changed! To see that the value actually changed in the list you'll need to look at the list. I shall also update my answer with the information that the standard C++ library containers actually make a copy of the original object...

Comment: Mother of containers. Thank you so much!

Comment: Code style: wouldn't `it` and, say, `eit` make a bit more sense instead of `it` and `end`?

Comment: @Joker_vD: I don't think so: the `end` is an immovable position. Yes, it could move in theory but in the above loop it surely won't. Nor would it move in any other single pass traversal while `it` is intended to move.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Well, my main reason for not using `end` is that it's, well, how would you ADL `end`? `auto it(begin(bob.pets)), end(end(bob.pets));`?

Comment: @Joker_vD: Since I fully qualify all names, it isn't a problem: `auto it(std::begin(bob.pets)), end(std::end(bob.pets));` ah, OK, I see what you mean: with ADL (i.e. preceding the statement with `using std::begin; using std::end;`) you don't have qualification...

Comment: @Joker_vD: thinking a bit about the issue, I realize why I haven't encountered the problem: I don't use loops ;) I'd rather write `std::for_each(begin(bob.pets), end(bob.pets), [](Pet const& p) { std::cout << p.age << '\n'; });` The only place where my algorithm implementations would use `begin()` and `end()` is in the range-version of the algorithms but these would immediately delegate the results to the iterator version.