# How do I mutate elements in a container in a loop?

Tags: c++

Have a list of objects and call a function by each object, but canot keep the context, example:

```
std::list<Ob> objs;
Ob ob;
ob.settings(/*...*/);
objs.push_back(ob);
/*...*/
for (Ob obj : objs)
{
    obj.increase();
}
```

The `increase()` function sum a local var, example:

```
class Ob
{
    private:
        int a = 0;
```

And ...

```
Ob::increase(){ this->a++; }
```

But `a` increase only in inner loop, if call 10 times canot keep last value.

Howto keep the context of object?

Comment: Pass a reference. `Ob &obj: objs`

Comment: see [C++ Object variables in list don't update during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288313/c-object-variables-in-list-dont-update-during-iteration/48288346#48288346).

Comment: By the way, `this->a++;` is overly verbose. `a++;` is sufficient. And `++a;` would be perfect.

Comment: While `a++;` or `++a;` is sufficient for the compiler, I personally like a little verbosity like `this->` or `m_` to quickly distinguish member variables from local variables and parameters. Sure, in this made-up example it's obvious even without such prefixes but in large code bases it can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing by value (i.e. copying the object in the list and modifying that) rather than passing by reference (which means modifying the actual item in the list). See below for a simple program illustrating this

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class Obj
{
public:
    void increase() { count++; }
    void printCount() { std::cout << count << '\n'; }
private:
    int count = 0;
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::list<Obj> passByValueObjs;
        Obj obj;
        passByValueObjs.push_back(obj);

        for (Obj obj : passByValueObjs)
        {
            obj.increase();
        }

        for (Obj obj : passByValueObjs)
        {
            obj.printCount();
        }
    }
    {
        std::list<Obj> passByReferenceObjs;
        Obj obj;
        passByReferenceObjs.push_back(obj);

        for (Obj &obj : passByReferenceObjs)
        {
            obj.increase();
        }

        for (Obj obj : passByReferenceObjs)
        {
            obj.printCount();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> for (Ob obj : objs)
> ```

This creates a copy in every loop iteration and discards it when the loop iteration is finished.

You want to use a reference instead:

```
for (Ob& obj : objs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying a copy of the object.

Change

```
for (Ob obj : objs)
```

to

```
for (Ob &obj : objs)
```